# Java regex: custom URL

Tags: java, regex

How can I create a regex, which matches a URL which:

- Contains: **q=help**

**AND**

- Doesn't contains: **sort=**

Some example URLs, which would match the regex:

- http://www.example.com/homepage?q=help
- http://www.example.com/homepage?page=1&q=help&pagesize=25

Some example URLs, which would not match the regex:

- http://www.example.com/homepage?sort=date
- http://www.example.com/homepage?q=help&sort=date
- http://www.example.com/homepage?sort=date&q=help
- http://www.example.com/homepage?page=1

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a pure string option, you could use `String#matches`:

```
String url = "http://www.example.com/homepage?q=help";
if (url.matches("(?!.*\\?.*\\bsort=).*\\?.*\\bq=help.*")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

The pattern says to:

```
(?!.*\\?.*\\bsort=)    assert that sort= does NOT occur in the query string
.*\\?.*\\bq=help.*     then match a URL with q=help in the query string
```

Comment: thank you! it works :) could you please provide a little explanation of the regex?